# Clarification: "Who is the artist of this image appearing in an article about a Russian space laser?"

Tags: discussion

[Who is the artist of this image appearing in an article about a Russian space laser?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27852/58)

This question was previously titled (and worded internally) as being about a "space-based" laser. The laser is not planned to be space-based (which would mean the laser is in space) and the article never claimed as much either. I suggest we keep the question referring to "space laser" as in the article and not "space-based laser", because we do not need to suggest to viewers that anyone is planning to put a laser cannon in space when that is not being proposed.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45133932#45133932

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @uhoh It is not a question but a discussion for clarification of the content dispute. Standard procedure for a rollback war. The rollback war was unintentional so no harm done here.